# Image too high res for container makes image look blurry

Tags: css, image

I'm a little confused by this and not sure how to search for answers.

I have a PNG that is 442px x 101px inside a container with "max-width: 146px; max-height: 28px;". This makes the resolution higher than what would be needed to be, but it looks blurry. When I change the container size, for testing purposes, to get the resolution closer to 2x, such as "max-width: 221px x 50px", the image looks much better.

This container is for user generated logos, so I avoided being too specific with the resolutions and sizing. Some logos are squarish, some are wide. I assumed that if I make it so that the images are always above 2x, it will look good. I can't really enforce users to make an exact size.

I was under the impression that if an image is larger enough than the container, it will display fine. This image scale right now is about 3.03x. Is there some requirement that the effective scale needs to be a perfectly clean number? If that's the case, is there an accepted way to fix this? I'm wondering if I will have to automatically resize the images users upload first.

Comment: I would recommend specifying a width in css even if it’s done using calc or a pct.  max-width and max-height without an accompanying width or height respectively sometimes produce unexpected side effects in my experience.  Also - you absolutely can (and should) force users to pick a specific size (or at least a max-size).  Even if you end up with blank space, you can let them choose the background color to avoid weird contrasts

Answer (score 0):

When you scale images, some anomalies are going to show up, either if you make them bigger (obvious) or when you shrink them down. In both cases, whatever is rendering it has to "invent" more pixels or guess on what pixel goes where.

Have you tried the CSS [image-rendering](https://www.w3docs.com/learn-css/image-rendering.html) property?